# Which python library for supervised learning of HMMs?

Tags: python, markov-hidden-model, library

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
timestamp  sensor1   sensor2  sensor3  sensor4    sensor5  action
       1    0.05       0.04    0.10      0.39      0.59      A1
       2    0.25       0.14    0.11      0.34      0.59      A2
       3    0.15       0.34    0.13      0.36      0.59      A3
    .......
```

Since I have the observations (sensor1-sensor5) and the corresponding labels (A1, A2, A3, etc.) for each timestamp, I want to perform supervised learning using a hidden markov model.

Which library could I use to learn the observation distribution and the parameters of the HMM ? Thank you!
P.S. : I already took a look at hmmlearn, but it seems to be only for unsupervised learning.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any specific reason for choosing HMM?

Answer (score 0):

The libarary pomegranate(https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate)implements HMM with Gaussian mixture model. The example of HMM is as follows :

```
from pomegranate import *
dists = [NormalDistribution(5, 1), NormalDistribution(1, 7), NormalDistribution(8,2)]
trans_mat = numpy.array([[0.7, 0.3, 0.0],
                             [0.0, 0.8, 0.2],
                             [0.0, 0.0, 0.9]])
starts = numpy.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.0])
ends = numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.1])
model = HiddenMarkovModel.from_matrix(trans_mat, dists, starts, ends)
```

Comment: How to train the HMM in a supervised manner with my data ?

Comment: See also this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55426513/1967571